# how to create agg func to handle divide by 0 in pandas?

Tags: pandas

For my analysis i need to re-use custom aggregations for RPC (revenue per click). I need to apply them to groups which may have edge cases where the denominator is 0.

The method below throws a warning and casts the aggregation as `inf`, whereas in my context `NA` is more appropriate.

This is probably a very simple question, but can someone please explain:

- how to modify `aggfunc` so that it avoids dividing by zero. (not looking for help on how to change or cast the values)
- does this warning cause any performance issues or unanticipated behavior?
- in general, how do you add row-level logic calculations in `aggfunc`? How would you add a column that calculates the stdv of RPC within each group?

---

```
print(pd.__version__)
clicks = [5, 8, 6, 6, 0, 4, 3, 7, 9, 4]
rev = [2.96, 3.94, 4.83, 2.94, 4.53, 4.66, 3.5 , 4.56, 2.41, 3.77]
group = ['A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
df = pd.DataFrame({'group':group,'clicks':clicks,'rev':rev})

def aggfunc(row):
    d = {
        'rpc' : row['rev'].sum() / row['clicks'].sum(),
        'rev' : row['rev'].sum(),
        'clicks' : row['clicks'].sum()
    }
    return pd.Series(d)

print(df.groupby('group').apply(aggfunc))

0.23.4
            rpc    rev  clicks
group                         
A      0.383571   5.37    14.0
B      0.671000   6.71    10.0
C      0.721765  12.27    17.0
D      0.838182   9.22    11.0
F           inf   4.53     0.0

/Users/jselenkow/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

Note: for more context- i know that you can do the sums without using apply function, but i find this method useful and convenient as i can define which columns to preserve

Comment: have you looked at `try-catch`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def aggfunc(row):
    d = {
        'rpc' : row['rev'].sum() / row['clicks'].sum() if row['clicks'].sum() != 0 else np.nan,
        'rev' : row['rev'].sum(),
        'clicks' : row['clicks'].sum()
    }
    return pd.Series(d)
```

Output:

```
            rpc    rev  clicks
group                         
A      0.383571   5.37    14.0
B      0.671000   6.71    10.0
C      0.721765  12.27    17.0
D      0.838182   9.22    11.0
F           NaN   4.53     0.0
```

Comment: thank you! that's exactly what i was looking for. The pandas documentation doesn't do a good job explaining what's really happening when you pass rows/groups to aggfunc like this. it seems that the function syntax is similar to `lambda` without the keyword. Any documentation/ tutorials you can point me to would be great :)

Comment: Well, to be honest @Jonathan I use Stack Overflow as my tutorials and this is Python's Ternary Operator, conditional expression http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html.